# Reliable 110 & 230V AC line detection on 3.3V GPIO

Tags: mosfet, ac, mains, detection, line

A manufacturer provided the following circuit, to detect AC line voltage in a small IoT module (non-isolated power supply).

[image: AC Line detection circuit]

SW1 is pulled up with an external 10 kOhm resistor and connected to the Input of an ESP32 for pulse detection.

- **R5, R6:** 180 kOhm
- **R19:** 15 kOhm
- **ZD2:** 100 nF Cap
- **Q3:** MMBT2222A Transistor ([data sheet](https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=e4eb6c5b-e042-4221-9434-496a4cab3380&fn=Datasheet+Transistor+MMBT2222A+CJ+SOT23.pdf&ct=1611053086497&tl=share-document&rf=link))

There is however a problem with induced voltages ([similar to this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10933/why-does-voltage-still-exists-when-a-circuit-is-broken-by-a-3-way-switch) I guess) in the wire connected to S1, due to other cables conducting 230V AC nearby. I can sometimes measure up to 100V AC with a multimeter on the cable I connect to S1 (even if it is not connected to the S1 input of the IoT module yet).

A suggestion of the manufacturer was to switch the circuit to a MOSFET, but this didn't help much either.

- **R5, R6:** 150 kOhm
- **R19:** 7.5 kOhm
- **ZD2:** 100 nF Cap
- **Q3:** HSS2300A MOSFET ([data sheet](https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=a604a89a-d759-440d-98e9-b139140641e4&fn=Datasheet+MOSFET+HSS2300A.pdf&ct=1611053120489&tl=share-document&rf=link))

I tried playing around a bit with the resistor values (see this [simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgosgCgAnEQjFEFPPJlkbBVqsHnh1GzVtkKcxIACzZ+4IfAZdWM4oVUVCVAZTi0AxiByb1m09t3hYwu3bABTALTlneaNjAIwk7MWwWYkgZchg4MFoAN1lfHhDYzWw8GShwGh4UJGsYBFoAMxBiMDUNIowzMvl08JQVMiS0crM4NLBhaOQOHhSuznkc2SpsTzTdaDyAd0Se1Jk4hGJ+Wmn5zUXWaQ2oFa1ty226aYOl5opTo7Pt9u7D3ZvOa-x+3suGoap3mSE2XfeBvqZKh1Y4SKwmMF3UGVTTFUqaEEQmFacw7abSVEY6qXaQSKTcXjLVZxdicNbxVI47gIHR7C5-CoUEpXekAczOhBQqXehBkOQZmk53MZUNkZVJMwllxpwO60ilu1REplbG6dAA9mxyLy0nziFI+VBoApWJgeCAAJIAOwADgBXAAutE1YG1lKG+rY42EDRpWXSrFd5oA4gBDB2OZ3gVI6qh6x5GuCcpCm6PmgDyjvtTqAA)), to get the Gate voltage of the MOSFET below the threshold voltage of 0.3V (according to the data sheet), but didn't find a solution that worked reliably in hardware either. I basically need a circuit that detects 110 & 230V AC, but ignores the induced voltages from coupling. I guess another option would be to put a huge capacitor in front of the MOSFET, but to not change the existing PCB too much, as I would like to stick with the existing packages of the parts. If there is however a huge improvement by changing this, I am willing to re-layout the PCB.

- R5, R6: 1206 package
- R19: 0805 package
- ZD2: 1206 package
- Q3: SOT-23 package

Thank you!

EDIT: another Image from an alternative circuit added, see reply and comments below. [image: Voila]

Comment: In schematic  ZD2 diode, in the list capacitor.

Comment: You want to detect 110VAC but at the same time you want to ignore 'up to' 100VAC induced. I don't see how that would be possible. You'd better properly shield the detect cable in order to reduce the induced voltage.

Comment: @user263983 yes, sorry. I got the schematic from a manufacturer, they apparently had a Zehnerdiode placed there before, and only changed the BOM document to the Capacitor.

Comment: @gommer the 100V AC I detect are just an induced voltage if I understand right, so there should almost be no current flowing... And somehow manufacturers like Allterco with their Shelly devices and Eltako manage it as well. Otherwise reliably detecting only 230V AC would also be good in a first step.

Answer (score 1):

> I basically need a circuit that detects 110 & 230V AC, but ignores the
> induced voltages from coupling.

Your circuit is far too sensitive for just detecting the presence of mains voltage. Reduce the value of R19 until it just manages to detect the lowest AC voltage you want, eg. 90 VAC. With the MMBT2222A a value of 2.2 kΩ should work.

I don't recommend using a FET because the Gate threshold voltage is not very precise.

With R19 = 2.2k this circuit should handle induced current of up to ~150 uA rms, which corresponds to ~2 nF of capacitive coupling at 240 VAC 50 Hz. If you still get false detection then you may have to add a load to shunt way the 'leakage' current. A 0.1 uF capacitor would allow up to ~30 nF of capacitive coupling, but it would have to be mains rated and therefore quite bulky.

Comment: Thank you! So a few more questions:

1. instead of using the MMBT2222A, could I use a MOSFET with a more precise Gate threshold voltage? Do you have any recommendations?

2. instead of using a MOSFET in general, should I switch back to a Transistor? I found this example (https://imgur.com/1Qruig6), which works quite well in my simulations.

3. the Capacitor as a load, would be between N and S1 terminal, right? And since it is not isolated basically parallel to R19 and ZD2?

Comment: MOSFETs in general do not have well defined Gate threshold value, so you should switch back to using a bipolar transistor. Yes, capacitor would go between N and S1. Note that it should be 'X' rated for connection directly across the mains. For some reason imgur.com has stopped working on my computer. Do you have a direct link to the example?

Comment: I added the image at the end of the original post